# why does apache executes all commands from my shell script but not java's one?

Tags: java, php, apache, shell

I'm trying to execute java by using shell script through the php's `exec` function

```
<?php
  exec("./test.sh", $output, $exit_code);

  foreach($output as $key => $val){
    echo $key . " ". $val . "<br/>";
  }

  echo "exit code " . $exit_code;
?>
```

Here my script `test.sh` is the following

```
echo "Hello world!";
java -version;
ls -l; 
pwd;
```

Here is the result where the output exit_code of `exec` is equal to 0

```
0 Hello world!
1 total 18468
2 drwxrwxr-x 4 leonzo leonzo 4096 mars 22 06:45 assets
3 drwxrwxr-x 2 leonzo leonzo 4096 mars 22 06:45 backup
4 drwxrwxr-x 2 leonzo leonzo 4096 mars 22 06:57 com
5 drwxrwxr-x 2 leonzo leonzo 4096 mars 22 06:45 content
6 -rw-rw-r-- 1 leonzo leonzo 1096 mars 22 06:45 index.php
7 drwxrwxr-x 2 leonzo leonzo 4096 mars 22 06:57 mcd
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 leonzo leonzo 153 mars 23 14:58 test_jar.php
9 -rw-rw-r-- 1 leonzo leonzo 152 mars 23 14:58 test_jar.php~
10 -rwxrwxrwx 1 leonzo leonzo 129 mars 23 15:08 test.sh
11 -rwxrwxrwx 1 leonzo leonzo 119 mars 23 15:02 test.sh~
12 -rw------- 1 leonzo leonzo 18844395 mars 23 14:45 videcom.jar
13 /home/leonzo/Documents/workspace/quifaitquoi
exit code 0
```

It clean that all command from my shell script have been execute unless java. What is the reason of such a behavior, is there something special to do in order to make java work fine ?

**EDITION**

indeed java is install on my computer

```
>java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What is the output if you simply run `sh test.sh` in a command line? Does the output have the java version?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my wild guess: Is java installed on this machine? Does the console have defaults settings that prevents error messages to be displayed?

Please give us some more details about your setup (environment).

Comment: i've edit the question, indeed java is installed on my Linux machine

Comment: @Fopa Léon Constantin: Does your script work under your user? Are you sure the php process runs under the same user account? I think "simmant" also gave a good answer.

Comment: I code clearly works fine and nothing change when i put JAVA_HOME in the environment variable

Answer (score 0):

As per the Linux system its better to also save the path of JAVA_HOME variable in .bashrc file which is hidden inside the home folder of the user..

set JAVA_HOME like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/you-java-version .

 export JAVA_HOME 

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: nothing change after i update the variable environement